# Thread leak while using javax.websocket client

Tags: java, websocket, memory-leaks

I'm trying to build an app that connects and disconnects to/from a server using websockets on demand but for some reason I'm encountering a thread leak.

This example code is connecting and disconnecting from the server in a loop to simulate this.
Here's the code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.WebSocketContainerFactoryBean;

import javax.websocket.ClientEndpointConfig;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.Endpoint;
import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig;
import javax.websocket.MessageHandler;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class App {
    private static final String TOKEN = "...";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            Session session = connect();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            session.close();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }

    private static Session connect() throws Exception {
        var clientEndpointConfigConfigurator = new ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator() {
            @Override
            public void beforeRequest(Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
                headers.put("Authorization", List.of("Bearer " + TOKEN));
                super.beforeRequest(headers);
            }
        };

        var clientEndpointConfig = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create()
                .configurator(clientEndpointConfigConfigurator)
                .build();

        var webSocketContainerFactoryBean = new WebSocketContainerFactoryBean();
        webSocketContainerFactoryBean.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(500 * 1024);

        return webSocketContainerFactoryBean.getObject().connectToServer(
                new MyEndpoint(),
                clientEndpointConfig,
                new URI("..."));
    }

    public static class MyEndpoint extends Endpoint {
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyEndpoint.class);

        @Override
        public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
            LOG.info("Connected");
            session.addMessageHandler(new MyMessageHandler());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
            LOG.info("Closed");
            super.onClose(session, closeReason);
        }
    }

    public static class MyMessageHandler implements MessageHandler.Whole<String> {
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyMessageHandler.class);

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String message) {
            LOG.info("Message received");
        }
    }
}
```

The misbehaving threads are:

```
"WebSocketClient-SecureIO-1" #32 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 cpu=273.23ms elapsed=18.56s tid=0x000000011e80c400 nid=0x550b waiting on condition  [0x00000001735f2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@17.0.2/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000700800458> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@17.0.2/LockSupport.java:341)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(java.base@17.0.2/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:506)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(java.base@17.0.2/ForkJoinPool.java:3463)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(java.base@17.0.2/ForkJoinPool.java:3434)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@17.0.2/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1623)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(java.base@17.0.2/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@17.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@17.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@17.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@17.0.2/Thread.java:833)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"WebSocketClient-SecureIO-2" #33 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 cpu=409.57ms elapsed=18.56s tid=0x000000011e80be00 nid=0x7c07 waiting on condition  [0x00000001733e6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@17.0.2/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000700800458> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@17.0.2/LockSupport.java:341)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(java.base@17.0.2/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:506)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(java.base@17.0.2/ForkJoinPool.java:3463)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(java.base@17.0.2/ForkJoinPool.java:3434)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@17.0.2/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1623)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(java.base@17.0.2/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@17.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@17.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@17.0.2/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@17.0.2/Thread.java:833)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

and that pair is created for each of my connections and is never closed.

According to the source code:
https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java#L550
those threads should be closed once the connection is closed.
Isn't `session.close();` enough?

[image: VisuaVM]
[image]